# Creating a new database in MySQL is always uses latin1_bin collate even if latin1_general_ci has been specified

Tags: mysql, collation

When creating a new database where I specify the character set and the collating sequence the database is created with the correct characterset but the wrong collating sequence.

```
-- DROP DATABASE test;

CREATE DATABASE test
CHARACTER SET latin1
COLLATE latin1_general_ci;
```

The code example should create a new database with "latin1" as the character set and "latin1_general_ci" as the collating sequence. However what happens is that the character set is set to "latin1" but the collating sequence is automatically changed to "latin1_bin". It does not matter which of the collating sequence names that I use for the "latin1" character set. I am not able to change this in the MySQL Workbench either.

This is the list of available collating sequences for the "latin1" character set on the server:

```
SHOW COLLATION WHERE Charset = 'latin1';
# Collation, Charset, Id, Default, Compiled, Sortlen, Pad_attribute
latin1_bin  latin1  47      Yes 1   PAD SPACE
latin1_danish_ci    latin1  15      Yes 1   PAD SPACE
latin1_general_ci   latin1  48      Yes 1   PAD SPACE
latin1_general_cs   latin1  49      Yes 1   PAD SPACE
latin1_german1_ci   latin1  5       Yes 1   PAD SPACE
latin1_german2_ci   latin1  31      Yes 2   PAD SPACE
latin1_spanish_ci   latin1  94      Yes 1   PAD SPACE
latin1_swedish_ci   latin1  8   Yes Yes 1   PAD SPACE
```

It seems that I should be able to create a database with the "latin1_general_ci" specified but whatever I choose from the list the database always gets created with "latin1_bin".

The default collating sequence is registered to "latin1_swedish_ci".

```
SHOW CHARACTER SET WHERE Charset = 'latin1';
# Charset   Description Default collation   Maxlen
latin1  cp1252 West European    latin1_swedish_ci   1
```

Even if I don't apply the collating sequence it still selects the "latin1_bin" collating sequence. I would expect the "latin1_swedish_ci" to be selected.

Can someone point me in the right direction? What option am I missing here?

```
MySQL Community Server 8.0.33 (Win64)
MySQL Workbench 8.0

Settings on the server includes:
character-set-server: utf8mb4
collation-server: utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci
default_collation_for_utf8mb4: utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci
using InnoDB
```

Comment: What makes you think the schema's collation is latin1_bin? Did you run `SHOW CREATE SCHEMA test` or `SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.SCHEMATA WHERE SCHEMA_NAME='test'`? Or are you only viewing it in the UI of MySQL Workbench?

Comment: I just tested your example on my instance of MySQL 8.0.32, and it creates the schema with the specified collation.

Comment: Thank you for the example code to verify the collating sequence and for testing that it does work for you.
I have tested with `SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.SCHEMATA WHERE SCHEMA_NAME='test'` and got `'# CATALOG_NAME, SCHEMA_NAME, DEFAULT_CHARACTER_SET_NAME, DEFAULT_COLLATION_NAME, SQL_PATH, DEFAULT_ENCRYPTION
'def', 'test', 'latin1', 'latin1_general_ci', NULL, 'NO'
` as result. It tells me that it indeed did make the right collating sequence. It must be an error in the MySQL Workbench then?

Comment: Yes, don't trust MySQL Workbench.

Comment: Please provide `SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES LIKE 'coll%';` and `SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES LIKE 'char%';`

Comment: You may want to view this bug: https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=92534 and click the "Affects Me" button to let them know yet another person is impacted by the bug. They have said this increases their priority for fixing bugs.